# Flask / WTForms: Right way to dynamic RadioField

Tags: python-3.x, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

i have problem with create dynamic RadioField with WTForms...

When i am trying basic example:

```
targeting_type = RadioField('Label', choices=[('value', 'description'),
                                              ('value_two', 'whatever')])
```

everything works fine.

When i am trying use this example:
[Flask-SQLAlchemy wtform based on db](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51579345/2278511)

in form are values from DB. But when i click on Submit button, page are "reloaded" but probably "without data".

Example of my views.py:

```
form = TargetingTypeForm()
form.targeting_type.choices = [
    (targeting_type.id, targeting_type.name)
    for targeting_type in SettingsTargetingType.query.all()]

if form.validate_on_submit():
    print('test', form.targeting_type.data)
```

After submit this form test data anen't printed :/

Please what is right way to create RadioField with WTForms + SQLAlchemy query?

Thanks for any answers.

Comment: Try `form.tergeting_type.coerse = int`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using ID as the value and I guess it's an Integer, u have to use `coerse` attribute on your `RadioField`!

Try this:

```
form = TargetingTypeForm()
form.targeting_type.choices = [
    (targeting_type.id, targeting_type.name)
    for targeting_type in SettingsTargetingType.query.all()]
form.targeting_type.coerse = int
if form.validate_on_submit():
    print('test', form.targeting_type.data)
```

or add the `coerse=int` to the `targeting_type` defination in `TargetingTypeForm` class